# What is this type of Ebike connector?

Tags: identification, power-connector

I have to find a replacement charger for a 72V electric dirt bike (unknown brand). The charge port is composed of two vertically centered pins with a Y-shaped separator. It looks like an ST3 connector, but it's a bit different. See picture below.

Can you help me identify this type of connector ? I've looked at https://connectorbook.com/ but couldn't find any match.

[image]

Comment: Could you find a charger for a 72V electric dirt bike and change the connector on the battery?

Comment: What is the model of dirtbike? The connector should be easier to lookup that way.

Comment: Sadly I cannot identify the model  of the dirtbike. My client inherited the bike and it has no signs/serial number/prints or whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

Without dimensions, I can't make a 100% ID but the "Y" shaped separator is distinctive enough that I am posting this as an answer.  It appears to be a [Chogori 23002515-01](http://www.chogori-tech.com/uploads/201606/5774dcbe5a4a6.pdf).

Comment: Actually, I believe it is the Chogori 23002515-03. Thanks a lot for putting me on the right track!